# Try Catch Block Creating an Object

Tags: c++

So for a class I am taking, we are getting practice with overloaded operators but more specifically we are designing a class for fractions(rational numbers). I am playing around with try-catch blocks and can't seem to get it to work like I want nor can I find any forums or articles on what I can't figure out. I'm trying to create the rational number object in a try-catch block to make sure that the value being put into the denominator is not a '0' and if it is, I let the catch block call the deconstructor for the object. I got this bit to work just fine but it seems that there is no way for me to use the object being created within the try-catch block later on in the code even if the constructor succeeded in assigning a non-zero value to the denominator. Is there a way to declare an object within a try-catch block to verify it won't throw an exception in its creation but still have it within the scope of the rest of the code that is outside the try-catch block but still in the same function or is there no way to pull it off?

Comment: In general, it is best to post the code you have already tried and are having difficulty with.

Comment: You do not need to explicitly call destructors for any local object in a catch clause.  They are automatically called when the object goes out of scope for *any reason*, including an exception being thrown.  This is why [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) works.

Answer (score 2):

`try` introduces a new scope. You cannot use your successfully constructed objects outside of the `try` because they have gone out of scope and have been destructed. This is true for objects created in any block such as a `for` or `if`, or any set of `{ }` braces for that matter. What you want to do is move the code that depends on the object into the `try`.

For example:

```
try {
  Rat rat1(3, 1);
  Rat rat2(2, 4);
  Rat rat3 = rat1 + rat2;
  std::cout << rat3 << std::endl;
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
  // above should not throw
}

try {
  Rat rat1(3, 1);
  Rat rat2(2, 0);  // throws
  Rat rat3 = rat1 + rat2;
  std::cout << rat3 << std::endl;
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
  // code here will execute
}
```